# How to animate nested content when animated parent slide moves into viewport, not using scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm looking to use javascript to animate the content of a nested DIV within an parent slide when the parent slide moves into the viewport.

At the moment, the content in the nested DIV only animates once a scroll command is also triggered after the parent slide moves onto the screen. I believe this is because the slide motion is animated and not scroll controlled.

The same issue is at play in this JSFiddle demo I created to explore the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/9dz3ubL1/

(The animated movement of the slide from right to left in this demo has been created to test for this problem, to replicate the motion of the slide without scrolling; it is not actually a feature of the development proper).

My question is, how can I script for the animations to be triggered for each nested DIV, when each slide element moves into the viewport, without requiring a scroll function?

Thanks for any help. Here's the script I'm using to control opacity and other CSS stylings.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    /* Reveal hidden_header delayed */
    $('.hidden_header').each(function(i) {
      var center_of_object = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();
      var center_of_window = $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width();
      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if (center_of_window > center_of_object) {
        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 500);
        $(this).animate({
          'right': '0'
        }, 1500);
      }
    });
    /* Reveal hidden_content delayed */
    $('.hidden_content').each(function(i) {
      var center_of_object = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();
      var center_of_window = $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width();
      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if (center_of_window > center_of_object) {
        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 3000);
        $(this).animate({
          'bottom': '0'
        }, 3500);
      }
    });
    /* Reveal button delayed */
    $('.button').each(function(i) {
      var center_of_object = $(this).offset().left + $(this).outerWidth();
      var center_of_window = $(window).scrollLeft() + $(window).width();
      /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
      if (center_of_window > center_of_object) {
        $(this).animate({
          'opacity': '1'
        }, 5000);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your slide motion is animated fully (not incremental as it is in the jsfiddle you linked) then jQuery provides you with the ability to perform an action after your animation is complete.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Look at the options you can use for the animation function. One of them is called done. You can assign a function to the done option and that function will be called when your animation is complete.

Using one of your animates as an example, the syntax may look like this:

```
    $(this).animate({
              'opacity': '1'
            }, {duration: 3000, done: function () {
                 //animate some stuff here
    }};
```

Note that I just picked a random animation from your code. I'm not sure exactly when you want to perform the animation of the content, but you can use this technique anywhere you use a jQuery animate.

I've used this before to control nested animations in a slideshow format and it has worked very well! I hope this what you wanted.

Comment: Of course, that's the most elegant solution! Well spotted and thank you for the help! :D